# How to refresh my fragment after clicking ok in dialog

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

So I want to refresh my fragment after I click OK in my dialog fragment. How do I do that?

This is my DialogMap which has button OK after which was clicked it Should reload MapFragment. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

navigate to this fragment using NavController like that

```
fun refresh(bundle: Bundle) { //->if you don't won't to send a data don't use a bundle 
    navController?.popBackStack() //-> it's because you must delete one step from navigation 
    navController?.navigate(
        R.id.yours_fragment_id,
        bundle
    )
}
```

Comment: Hmmm could you write this in Java?